# How can I edit a layout's textview in a class with a different layout

Tags: java, android

Let's say I have class MainActivity which has main_activity as its layout. I have a String in the class and I want to set my other layout's textview (secondactivity) with the value of that string. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Comment: I don't want to go into another Activity , the link you sent has no relevance

Comment: Your question states you have another layout, and you put secondactivity in brackets.

Comment: Only one Activity is active at once, why do you need to change text you can't see? Intents/SharedPreferences/Database/Files are the correct answers to your question, regardless of how the second Activity is started

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use a String that's in another Java class, you have to create a static String in the first class.

In your MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity {

    public static String yourString = "Your string";

}
```

Then were you want to set the text of the TextView:

```
yourTextView.setText(MainActivity.yourString);
```

Comment: Non final public static variables are bad practice in Android